# Delete trigger doesn't work while add trigger work correctly?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

The Delete trigger doesn't work while the add trigger works correctly.

It should works like this: "When I delete a record in score table that has subject_id = 1 and score > 8, exellentEng will -1  in class table" 
I don't know why. Help me

```sql
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[deleteExellentEnglishStudent]
ON [dbo].[dbo_score]
AFTER DELETE AS 
    BEGIN
      UPDATE x SET
        exellent_Eng -=1
      FROM dbo.dbo_class x
      JOIN dbo.dbo_student s ON s.class_id = x.class_id
      JOIN dbo.dbo_score c ON c.student_id = s.student_id
      WHERE (c.subject_id = 1 AND c.score >= 8)
      and c.score_id in (SELECT Deleted.score_id FROM Deleted)
    END
```

```sql
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[addExellentEnglishStudent] ON [dbo].[dbo_score]
    AFTER INSERT AS 
    BEGIN
      UPDATE x SET
        exellent_Eng += 1
      FROM dbo.dbo_class x
      JOIN dbo.dbo_student s ON s.class_id = x.class_id
      JOIN dbo.dbo_score c ON c.student_id = s.student_id
      WHERE (c.subject_id = 1 AND c.score >= 8)
      AND c.score_id IN
      (select Inserted.score_id from Inserted)
    END
```

Comment: Add some select statements e.g. `select * from Deleted` to the trigger and then do the delete from SSMS so you can see the results. Then make a select similar to your update so you can see what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The row won't exist in the `dbo_score` table because its an `after` trigger, so the row has already been deleted. Instead use the `Deleted` pseudo-table directly e.g.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[deleteExellentEnglishStudent]
ON [dbo].[dbo_score]
AFTER DELETE AS 
BEGIN
  UPDATE x SET
    exellent_Eng -=1
  FROM dbo.dbo_class x
  JOIN dbo.dbo_student s ON s.class_id = x.class_id
  JOIN dbo.Deleted c ON c.student_id = s.student_id
  WHERE (c.subject_id = 1 AND c.score >= 8)
END
```

Note: As I said on your other question you might find it easier to write and maintain these triggers if they compute the value absolutely each time, rather than working on the difference. Then you can use the same logic for insert, update and delete e.g. something like:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[deleteExellentEnglishStudent]
ON [dbo].[dbo_score]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
  UPDATE x SET
    exellent_Eng = (select count(*) from dbo.dbo_score where c.subject_id = 1 AND c.score >= 8)
  FROM dbo.dbo_class x
  JOIN dbo.dbo_student s ON s.class_id = x.class_id
  where S.studentid in (select student_id from Inserted union all select student_id from Deleted)
END
```